# Dynamic array for Promise.all() in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I want to add promises to array passed to `Promise.all()` dynamically

```
var P = require('bluebird');

var firstPromise = P.resolve().then(function () {
  console.log('1 completed');
});

var all = [firstPromise];

for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
  (function closure(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      all.push(P.delay(1000).then(function () {
        console.log(i + ' completed');
      }));
    }, 0);
  })(i);

}

P.all(all).then(function () {
  console.log('finish');
});
```

Output is

```
1 completed
finish
2 completed
3 completed
4 completed
```

I want to print finish after when all my promises will be resolved. I know that I have incorrect code, but how to rewrite it to solve my question?

Comment: Promise.all waits for an existing array, your array changes after the `.all` call.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but my question was how to rewrite my code to solve that dynamic changes

Comment: Simply put - you should not have `settimeout` in your code to begin with, you should convert callback using APIs to use promises and then chain and have `.all` on the chain - I can add an answer explaining this if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the promises after the `P.all` call because of your setTimeout.

That's not how promises work.
You have to push all promises before calling `Promise.all`:

```
var all = [firstPromise];

for (var i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
  (function closure(i) {
    all.push(new P(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        P.delay(1000).then(function () {
          console.log(i + ' completed');
        }).then(resolve).catch(reject);
      }, 0);
    }));
  })(i);
}

P.all(all).then(function () {
  console.log('finish');
});
```